# template argument deduction with strongly-typed enumerations

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, strong-typing, template-argument-deduction

If I have a normal (weak) enumeration, I can use its enumerated values as non-type template parameters, like so:

```
enum { Cat, Dog, Horse };

template <int Val, typename T> bool magic(T &t)
{
    return magical_traits<Val>::invoke(t);
}
```

and call it as: `magic<Cat>(t)`

as far as I can see, if I have a strongly-typed enumeration and don't want to hard-code the enumeration type, I end up with:

```
enum class Animal { Cat, Dog, Horse };

template <typename EnumClass, EnumClass EnumVal, typename T> bool magic(T &t)
{
    return magical_traits<EnumVal>::invoke(t);
}
```

and now I have to write: `magic<Animal, Animal::Cat>(t)`, which seems redundant.

Is there any way to avoid typing out both the enum class and the value, short of

```
#define MAGIC(E, T) (magic<decltype(E), E>(T));
```

Comment: Why not `template <EnumClass EnumVal, typename T> bool magic(T &t)`?  Are you going to pass other types of enums to this function?  I can't think you are, since `magical_traits<>` only takes one parameter itself, and it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Hmm, I over-simplified the example then: yes, the idea is to handle multiple enum classes without duplication. It's a shame, because it could deduce the enum class fine if I passed the _value_ as a function argument, but not if it's a template parameter.

Comment: Fact is, this is exactly the point of `enum class`es, to be a different type each, and to be especially distinct from `int` and the likes.

Comment: True; it's a shame that deduction won't work for non-type parameters the same as for type parameters here. I can deduce the containing class and member type from a single pointer-to-member argument, but there's no way to do the equivalent for a strongly-typed enumerated argument.

Comment: why not just `template <Animal a,typename T> bool magic(T &t)` ?

Comment: That works, it's just limited to one enum class. I was originally hoping to make the enum class and value _both_ template parameters (and ideally deduce the class from the value), but because they're interdependent it's not straightforward.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do it like this, if you can use C++17

```
#include <type_traits>

enum class Animal { Cat, Dog, Horse };

template <typename EnumClass, EnumClass EnumVal> 
void magic_impl()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<EnumClass, Animal>);
    static_assert(EnumVal == Animal::Cat);
}

template <auto EnumVal>
void magic()
{
    magic_impl<decltype(EnumVal), EnumVal>();
}

int main()
{
    magic<Animal::Cat>();
}
```

demo:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ac5095e8434c9da

Comment: And it only took 5 years from first asking the question!

Comment: @Useless hah, it popped up on the question list because someone else posted an answer and I didn't look at the question date ;D, but I guess some people may find it helpful.

Comment: @Sopel: it's very helpful, I haven't even seen the `template <auto X>` syntax before!

Answer (score 12):

I'm sorry, I have to tell you that

### It is not possible

Take the macro, put it into a scary named header and protect it from your colleague's cleanup script. Hope for the best.

Comment: Time for some macro wrappers then ... or maybe I can survive a little repetition so long as I know it isn't just me.

Comment: Note for future reference: this answer is correct for C++11 (which is what I asked, and what is tagged). I moved the tick to the currently-accepted answer because it's great news and I wasn't previously aware of it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're only interested in the `enum`'s value, and not its type, you should be able to use a `constexpr` function to convert the value to an integer, avoiding repeating the type name.

```
enum class Animal { Cat, Dog, Horse };

template <typename T> constexpr int val(T t)
{
    return static_cast<int>(t);
}

template <int Val, typename T> bool magic(T &t)
{
    return magical_traits<Val>::invoke(t);
}

magic<val(Animal::Cat)>(t);
```

However, as pointed out already by others, if you want to make this depend on the type as well, it will not work.

Answer (score 2):

This question has an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9400758/186997) (upvoted).

While refactoring my own code, I figured out a more complete solution:

Step 1: using code I was writing:

```
template<typename V, typename EnumClass, EnumClass Discriminator>
class strong_type final // type-safe wrapper for input parameters
{
    V value;
public:
    constexpr explicit strong_type(V x): value{x} {}
    constexpr auto get() const { return value; }
};
```

Step 2: client code:

```
enum class color { red, green, blue, alpha };

// the part OP was asking about:
template<color C>
using color_channel = strong_type<std::uint8_t, color, C>;

using red = color_channel<color::red>; // single argument here
using green = color_channel<color::green>;
using blue = color_channel<color::blue>;
using alpha = color_channel<color::alpha>;
```