# C++ template specialization/overloading

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, non-type

First of all, I'm sorry for the vague title of this question. I wasn't sure how to summarize it.

The thing I want to achieve is the following, I want to be able to pass template non-type parameters of different types to the same class-template, resulting in different instantiations. Something like this:

```
Foo<1>();
Foo<'1'>(); // different types of object
```

I don't think this is possible, therefore I'm forced to do something like this

```
template <typename T, T Val>
struct Foo;

template <int Val>
struct Foo<int, Val> 
{};

template <char Val>
struct Foo<char, Val>
{};

//...

Foo<int, 1>();
Foo<char, '1'>();
```

such that `Foo` can be specialized based upon the first template parameter. However this complicates the syntax of the mini-language I'm trying to implement in my metaprogramming framework. Is there any technique available that allows me to distinguish `Foo<1>` from `Foo<'1'>`? Basically what I want to do is set a compile-time flag (in an enum) to indicate wheter an `int` or `char` was passed, without explicitly specifying them.

**EDIT**
The answers made me realize that my question implicates that I actually need (compile-time) instances of these objects. I don't...

Say that somehow the standard would permit me to overload a class template such that `Foo<1>` and `Foo<'1'>` are different types, and contain different values for their `flag` field. These types can then themselves be passed to another class template, which can inspect them and do interesting stuff with it, for example:

```
template <typename FooType>
struct Bar
{
    typedef typename If < FooType::flag, int, char >::Type Type;
};
```

This is all very easy to do when you have nothing against passing the type explicitly, but this seems superfluous...

Comment: Huh, I never thought about this. +1

Comment: Neither did I, 'till I needed it ;-)

Comment: This looks like a more general case of [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9400581/212858), whose answer I'm afraid waasn't encouraging

Comment: @Useless You're right, not very encouraging.

Comment: Would two templates one define as `template<int Val>` and one defined as `template<char Val>` work or would to compiler mutter about multiple definitions?

Comment: @Paranaix: Sorry I derped, previous comment removed. GCC says something about template parameters being redeclared.

Comment: I dont know whether this works or compiles at all because VS doesnt support constexpr fully yet, but you could give it atleast a try with GCC and maybe the approach already helps you: http://pastebin.com/Y04gi3hu 
The idea is to exploit type deduction (what we actually want/need) but with constexpr functions.

Comment: @Paranaix You forgot to indicate trailing return type in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use macro:

```
#define MAKE_FOO(value) \
    Foo<decltype(value), value>()
```

Actually, I think you need something like widespread function template `make_something` at compile-time. Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I was afraid of this being the only answer. Of course I already considered this option, but macro's are evil ;-) Will mark as answer if no-one has a better idea.

Comment: Whats about the same approach but with default template parameters? `template<typename T = decltype(Val), T Val>` But somehow im sure this wont compile :D

Comment: @Paranaix it wouldn't work because default parameters need to be filled from the right.

Comment: I ended up writing a macro to hide the ugly stuff from the end-user, even though this is very bad style... Marked as answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need the values available at compile-time but don't actually need them as part of the type, (As in, if you don't need `Foo<int, 1>` and `Foo<int, 2>` to be different types) then you can use a `constexpr` constructor along with a `constexpr` function to give rise to `Foo` instances at compile-time.

```
#define DECLTYPE_AUTO(expr) \
  -> decltype(expr) { return expr; }

template <typename T>
struct Foo {

  constexpr Foo(T t) : value(t) {}

  T value;

};  // Foo

template <typename T>
constexpr auto MakeFoo(T val)
    DECLTYPE_AUTO(Foo<T>(val));

static_assert(MakeFoo(2).value == 2, "");
static_assert(MakeFoo('1').value == '1', "");

int main() {}
```

Comment: Interesting... However I think it's not of much use to me. My fault entirely for not stating enough details in the question. Question edited :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
template <int Val>
struct Foo<int, Val> 
{
    static MyEnum tag = myTag1;
};


template <char Val>
struct Foo<char, Val>
{
    static MyEnum tag = myTag2;
};
```

Comment: And the purpose is what?

Comment: Distinguish Foo<1> from Foo<'1'>?

Comment: You still have to pass either `int` or `char` to `Foo`, which is exactly what I want to avoid. I want the compiler to deduce the type, like it does with function overloading. The [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9400581/212858) by Useless is about exactly the same problem, and it was then concluded that it's not possible...

Comment: Sure it is not possible. Therefore I thought the above approach could help you with your idea and simplify your life.

Comment: This is exactly what I already did in my opening post. If that had been satisfactory, I wouldn't have asked in the first place.

Comment: I got your question wrong. Your problem is instantiation of the instances not distinguishing them afterwards. Sorry.

Comment: @KitFisto Yup! No problem :-)