# force a strongly typed enum to participate in template overload resolution

Tags: c++, c++17

As per this question - [template argument deduction with strongly-typed enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400581/template-argument-deduction-with-strongly-typed-enumerations) - it seems challenging - if not impossible - to get strongly typed enumerators to participate in overload resolution.

if we have the following

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void ExternalFunction(const std::string& tag, int value)
{
    std::cout << tag << " - (int) " << value << std::endl;
}

void ExternalFunction(const std::string& tag, double value)
{
    std::cout << tag << " - (double) " << value << std::endl;
}

void ExternalFunction(const std::string& tag, const std::string& value)
{
    std::cout << tag << " - (string) " << value << std::endl;
}

class Wrapper
{
    public:
        virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

template <typename variable_type>
class VariableWrapper : public Wrapper
{
    public:
        VariableWrapper(variable_type variable) : variable(variable) {}
        
        void DoSomething() override
        {
            ExternalFunction("tag", variable);
        }
        
        variable_type& variable;        
};

template <typename enumerator, typename convert_to_string>
class EnumWrapper : public VariableWrapper<enumerator>
{
    public:

        EnumWrapper(enumerator& variable, convert_to_string encoder) : VariableWrapper<enumerator>(variable), encoder(encoder) {}

        void DoSomething() override
        {
            ExternalFunction("tag", encoder(VariableWrapper<enumerator>::variable));
        }
        
        convert_to_string encoder;
};

enum class StronglyTyped
{
    A,
    B,
    C
};

int main()
{
    StronglyTyped e = StronglyTyped::A;
    Wrapper* wrapper = new EnumWrapper(e, [](StronglyTyped S)->std::string{return "Test";});
    wrapper->DoSomething();
}
```

if we try to run this - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d555c4e3300ab05d - we get the errors

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void VariableWrapper<variable_type>::DoSomething() [with variable_type = StronglyTyped]':
main.cpp:31:14:   required from here
main.cpp:33:29: error: no matching function for call to 'ExternalFunction(const char [4], StronglyTyped&)'
   33 |             ExternalFunction("tag", variable);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: 'void ExternalFunction(const string&, int)'
    4 | void ExternalFunction(const std::string& tag, int value)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:4:51: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'StronglyTyped' to 'int'
    4 | void ExternalFunction(const std::string& tag, int value)
      |                                               ~~~~^~~~~
main.cpp:9:6: note: candidate: 'void ExternalFunction(const string&, double)'
    9 | void ExternalFunction(const std::string& tag, double value)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:9:54: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'StronglyTyped' to 'double'
    9 | void ExternalFunction(const std::string& tag, double value)
      |                                               ~~~~~~~^~~~~
main.cpp:14:6: note: candidate: 'void ExternalFunction(const string&, const string&)'
   14 | void ExternalFunction(const std::string& tag, const std::string& value)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:14:66: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'StronglyTyped' to 'const string&' {aka 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&'}
   14 | void ExternalFunction(const std::string& tag, const std::string& value)
      |                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Is it possible to get the strongly typed enumerator to participate in the overload resolution? I don't want to remove the strongly typing - which does remove this issue - as i will then have to use unique names between multiple enums

EDIT: i have removed the std::to_string from the question and updated the code accordingly as it was incorrectly being focused on.

Comment: Do you want to convert numerical value of the enum to string?

Comment: It should be possible to use strongly typed enumerators in overload resolution. Unfortunately, `std::to_string` is not overloaded for any strongly typed enumerators.

Comment: Cast the enum to an `int` in the call to `to_string`?

Comment: "*it seems challenging - if not impossible - to get strongly typed enumerators to participate in overload resolution.*" No, it's only "challenging" to get strongly-typed enumerators to act like integers. Because that's the whole point of being "strongly-typed".

Comment: no, in this case i don't want it to be an int, it's just the first of the errors that appear. i want the encode function to convert it to a string, as it should be selected from a list of strings.

Comment: the 'base' version of this is for handling actual integer, double, types, that can already run throw std::to_string. the enumerator should be done via a lookup in a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written your code incorrectly.

OK, so `EnumWrapper<>::DoSomething` overrides `VariableWrapper<T>::DoSomething`. So it won't be called by directly calling `DoSomething` on any `EnumWrapper` object.

But that doesn't mean `VariableWrapper<T>::DoSomething` doesn't *exist*. It does exist, and you can still call it by a qualified call. As such, when you instantiate `VariableWrapper<T>` for some particular `T`, the member functions of this template class must be valid.

And `VariableWrapper<T>::DoSomething` is not valid for any `T` which cannot be used to call `ExternalFunction` directly. This has nothing to do with enumerations specifically; it's purely about how you wrote your function.

You should instead make `EnumWrapper` not inherit from `VariableWrapper`. They both can inherit from `BaseWrapper`, but they have no business inheriting from one another. Alternatively you could make `ExternalFunction` itself a template that can resolve how to do whatever it is that it does for any given type.

Comment: Changing the derivation pattern does solve the problem. I guess it makes sense that the template arguments must also be valid. A bit annoying that it must derive separately, as there is shared functionality I now have to duplicate a bit of, but it does work.